# How to take a database dump for selective set of values in few tables

Tags: mysql

```
create table foo (id, val1, user_id,...)
create table bar (id, foo_id, val2, ...)
create table baz (id, bar_id, val3, ...)

select * from foo where user_id = 1;
select * from bar where id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)
select * from baz where id in (for all the above bars)
```

How do I write a dump command which does the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqldump -h yourhost -u username -p yourDatabase foo --where="user_id = 1" >dumpFile1
mysqldump -h yourhost -u username -p yourDatabase bar --where=" id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)" >dumpFile2
mysqldump -h yourhost -u username -p yourDatabase baz --where="id in (select * from bar where id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1))" >dumpFile3
```

Another option would be to export into CSV files.

```
select * from foo where user_id = 1 INTO OUTFILE 'C:/whatever'
```

or something like this. Have a look in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

**UPDATE:**

Not tested, but can you try this?

```
mysqldump -h yourhost -u username -p yourDatabase foo bar baz
--where="foo.user_id = 1" 
--where="bar.id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)" 
--where="baz.id in (select * from bar where id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1))" 
>dumpFile
```

**UPDATE 2:**

In the [manual](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqldump/) of mysqldump I see nothing about multiple WHERE clauses. So I'm afraid you have to do it in multiple steps.

Comment: Since you have different where clauses I don't think so.

Comment: I've tried and it seems indeed not to be possible in one step.